# PHP: get the value of TEXTBOX then pass it to a VARIABLE

Tags: php, variables, textbox, get

My Problem is:

I want to get the value of textbox1 then transfer it to another page where the value of textbox1 will be appeared in the textbox2.

Below is my codes for PHP:

```
<html>
<body>

<form name='form' method='post' action="testing2.php">

Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name" ><br/>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I also add the code below and the error is "Notice: Undefined index: name"

```
<?php 
$name = $_GET['name'];
echo $name;
?>
```

or

```
<?php 
$name = $_POST['name'];
echo $name;
?>
```

Comment: wrap it around `if (isset($_POST['name']))`

Comment: In your form you've specified the method `post`, so in your php code you should look for the value in the `$_POST` array, so `$_POST['name']`

Comment: And don't use `isset` as Dave Chen recommended, use `if( ! empty($_POST['name'])` instead.

Comment: Depends on what he wants. If he wants an empty name that is. Also, empty(0) returns false.

Comment: @Philistyne Brigid Bellisim - `Andrew Gibson` has a point about the naming convention. `"name"` will only cause confusion, and I suggest that when you write a form, it will help to use a naming convention such as `first_name` and `last_name` respectively. You could also use a shorter form such as `fname or f_name` - `lname or l_name`. It's only good practice ;-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In testing2.php use the following code to get the name:

```
if ( ! empty($_POST['name'])){
    $name = $_POST['name']);
}
```

When you create the next page, use the value of `$name` to prefill the form field:

```
Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>"><br/>
```

However, before doing that, be sure to use regular expressions to verify that the $name only contains valid characters, such as:

```
$pattern =  '/^[0-9A-Za-zÁ-Úá-úàÀÜü]+$/';//integers & letters
if (preg_match($pattern, $name) == 1){
    //continue
} else {
    //reload form with error message
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the information for valid characters. I can used it in the future :) and it works too!

Comment: This answer is good, it encourages the beginners to make their websites more secured!

Answer (score 4):

I think you should need to check for isset and not empty value, like form was submitted without input data so isset will be true This will prevent you to have any error or notice.

```
if((isset($_POST['name'])) && !empty($_POST['name']))
{
    $name = $_POST['name']; //note i used $_POST since you have a post form **method='post'**
    echo $name;
}
```

Comment: `empty() does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist.` So you only need just `empty` or just `isset`.

Comment: @DaveChen That's another issue - The OP should dive into tutorials and learn as he earns. ;-) In this equation, `$earns = "Knowledge";`

Comment: Oh. thank you so much.. It works!

I have last question... how can I transfer the variable of $name to a textbox?

Comment: @PhilistyneBrigidBellisima Look it up on the Web. There is a plethora of answers out there for you to `look` for. We don't write code for you, we try to help with issues you may have for some probable and inexplicable reason. Google `how to automatically insert text in a form field` or something to that affect. Enjoy the adventure, and happy coding! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You are posting the data, so it should be $_POST. But 'name' is not the best name to use.

```
name = "name"
```

will only cause confusion IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `testing2.php` you should print the `$_POST` array which contains all the data from the post. Also, `$_POST['name']` should be available. For more info check [$_POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) on [php.net](http://php.net).