# Getting the value of textbox

Tags: php, jquery, select

I have a select option, to get the value from this, I used jquery (please see below code). After I display the selected value in the textbox, I'm now having problem on how to get the value of textbox to process a such code. Even simply echo of the value is not working. What's the problem with the code? Please help. Thanks.

Select option:

```
<select name='shiptype' id='shiptype'>
   <option value="0">Please select...</option>
   <option value="LOC">LOCAL</option>
   <option value="IM">IMPORT</option>
</select>
```

Jquery:

```
$('#shiptype').change(function () {
  var selectedValue = $(this).val();
  var strloc = "LOCAL";
  var strimp = "IMPORT";
  if (selectedValue == "LOC") {
    $('#strkey').val(selectedValue);
  } else if (selectedValue == "IM") {
    $('#strkey').val(selectedValue);
  }         
 });
```

Text Field:

```
<input type='text' id='strkey' name='keyname' />
```

Display the value:

```
$key = $_POST['keyname'];
echo $key;
```

Comment: To make PHP show code from the client you need to send it to the PHP. Please look into Ajax PHP or submit the form it is in

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: get the value of TEXTBOX then pass it to a VARIABLE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17010975/php-get-the-value-of-textbox-then-pass-it-to-a-variable)

Comment: I assume you're submitting the form to the php page?

Comment: how are you sending the input? submitting the form? if so, can you add the form code? and its contents

Comment: actually the 2 option value LOCAL and IMPORT have corresponding tables. If local is selected, its table will show.

Comment: then if local is selected, the reference number (textbox) will start to LOC (sample: LOCCK2016-0000001). I want to get the value of select in which I get it through jquery then pass it to a textbox.

Comment: Show full example and tell us how you want to send the text box value to PHP

Comment: you can get the value using `alert` for testing : `alert($('#strkey').val());` and use ajax to post data and retrieve them to the table or whatever.

Comment: @EkoJunaidiSalam how can I use ajax to post data?

Comment: @EkoJunaidiSalam I can get the value but I can't use it to post data

Comment: Please refer [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for pass data using AJAX and get response from AJAX.

Comment: @KimlynTormes please check my Answer... Hope that explain everything. For more detail please refer to jQuery Documentation. Just Kausha Said before.

Comment: does the input content change when you select from dropdown i would add some alerts so you can see what is going on, with the assumption you do actually have it in form and post it, try to var_dump post array in php to see what you are sending

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code :

HTML file contains this below code. File name `test.html`.
Form to submit your data.

```
<form id="frm_post">
    <select name='shiptype' id='shiptype'>
        <option value="0">Please select...</option>
        <option value="LOC">LOCAL</option>
        <option value="IM">IMPORT</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="strkey">
    <input id="btn_post" type="button" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This is a `div` for your output.

```
<div>
    <p id="output"></p>
</div>
```

This is jquery for ajax call function.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#shiptype').change(function() {
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();
        var strloc = "LOCAL";
        var strimp = "IMPORT";
        if (selectedValue == "LOC") {
            $('#strkey').val(selectedValue);
            //alert($('#strkey').val());
        } else if (selectedValue == "IM") {
            $('#strkey').val(selectedValue);
            //alert($('#strkey').val());
        }
    });

    $("#btn_post").click(function(){
        var parm = $("#frm_post").serializeArray();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'your.php',
            data: parm,
            success: function (data,status,xhr) {
                console.info(data);
                $( "#output" ).html(data);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.info("Error post : "+error);
                $( "#output" ).html(error);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

And for PHP File to get the post value like this below. File name `your.php`.

```
<?php
    // $key = $_POST['keyname'];
    // echo $key;
    print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Your post result will be show up in output id. Hope this help you out. :D